# Read in SAS with two lines end and start at different positions

Tags: sas

I have two lines of observations to read in SAS.
It is a comma-delimited data set.
My code is as below:

```
DATA SASweek1.industry;
  INFILE "&Dirdata.Assignment1_Q6_data.txt" DLM="," DSD termstr=crlf TRUNCOVER;
  LENGTH Company $ 15;
  INPUT Company $ State $ Expense COMMA9. ;  
  FORMAT Expense DOLLAR9.;
  *INFORMAT Expense DOLLAR10.;
RUN; * not ready;
```

The raw data set looks like this:

[image]

I can print out the first line of observations well,
but the last "0" will go to the first position of the second 
line, becoming "0Lee's..". 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: What output do you get if you remove these lines `FORMAT Expense DOLLAR9.;
  *INFORMAT Expense DOLLAR10.;`

Comment: Put your data as text please, To work with it I would have to type it in. You need to use an INFORMAT (before INPUT) to specify the comma format and it can be read correctly. There's a full explanation and workaround details in this post here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/data-step-error/m-p/328641/highlight/true#M73381

Comment: On second thought that may not be close enough.

Comment: https://rit0-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/jc3992_rit_edu/EaIjSRv3bzpFvh0Kh0Rmx3wBTTPL99TTw6MEsMtkg8qiPw?e=Carf04  The output

Answer (score 1):

It is just doing what you told it to do.  You told it to read exactly 9 characters.

Normally you should not use formatted input mode with delimited data.  You prevent that by either adding the `:` (colon) prefix in front of the informat specification in the `INPUT` statement or removing the informat specification completely and using an `INFORMAT` statement to let SAS know what informat to use.

But your data is NOT properly delimited because the last field contains the delimiter, but the value is not enclosed in quotes.  So the commas make it look like two values instead of one.  The real solution is to fix the process that created the file to create a valid delimited file. It needs to quote the values with commas in them, or remove the commas from the numbers, or use a delimiter character that does not appear in the data.

Fortunately since it is the last field on the line you CAN use formatted input to read just that field.  Since you are using the `TRUNCOVER` option just set the width of the informat in the INPUT statement to the maximum.

```
DATA SASweek1.industry;
  INFILE "&Dirdata.Assignment1_Q6_data.txt" DLM="," DSD termstr=crlf TRUNCOVER;
  LENGTH Company $15 State $15 Expense 8;
  INPUT Company State Expense COMMA32. ;  
  FORMAT Expense DOLLAR9.;
RUN;
```

Comment: https://rit0-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jc3992_rit_edu/EWEfdYPoSVREjZWvl52j5hsB04BFMn8gcgF0olFdRWPTqw?e=oAt8SS is the LOG. It seemed the width of the variable "expense" has not resolved. After I changed COMMA32. to COMMA9. It printed out the first line as what I did but still, no next line :(

Comment: You lied to SAS. You told it that the end of line characters were CR + LF, but the log is showing that it is only LF.

Comment: @ Tom, you are completely right!!! I cheated the poor SAS before I even knew about it. I did not every think of that could be the issue since I read the textbook and felt it is safer to have that there no matter what. Would you mind letting me know how did you tell from the LOG that it is only LF? You touched SAS's heart as you know it well.

Comment: First clue is that it treated the two lines as one line. Then in the display of the values in the lines that caused the error you can see the Hex Codes for the characters. You can see that there is just the character `'0A'x` between the two lines.  That is a line feed. `'0D'x` is a carriage return.